# How can I diagnose this strange multicast issue?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, multicast

I originally meant to ask this question as a comment to [how can i diagnose our java ip multicast application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393726/how-can-i-diagnose-our-java-ip-multicast-application/8402424#8402424), but the question is too long to be a comment.

The basic setup is that my PC application creates a UDP multi-cast socket accepting all connections to that port (this is an isolated local network). I have a bridge connected to the same router trying to connect to this multicast socket. Authentication is done through checking the content of packet received through the multicast socket, upon which connection is established between the PC and the bridge.

This has been working until recently, when my application doesn't receive anything through the multicast socket anymore. However, as soon as I run the command `sudo tshark -n -V -i eth0 igmp`, the bridge is detected and connection established as usual.

What might possibly be causing this?

Comment: No real ideas here, but maybe it has something to do with tshark putting your nic in promiscuous mode.

Comment: Could test that by manually setting the promiscuous flag on eth0 and seeing if your apps work. If so check the sender's dest Mac address to see if it is correct for your multicast group, and matches what the receiver expects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try it.